# Swipe to refresh is not working if LazyGridView has no child in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using `SwipeRefresh` view in compose (from [accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/)). I have `LazyVerticalGrid` inside it, and grid populates paging data from network. If there's no content in paging data, i'm showing empty state view. When there's some data, swipe-to-refresh is working. Issue is, i'm not able to do swipe-to-refesh in `LazyVerticalGrid` if there's no data, but same is working in `LazyColumn` (both case has `NoContentView` shown).

```
@Composable
fun GridItems(
    searchViewModel: SearchViewModel
) {
    var isRefreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val posts = remember { searchViewModel.posts }.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { MyTopBar() }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        SwipeRefresh(
            state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing = isRefreshing),
            onRefresh = { searchViewModel.getPosts() }
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    cells = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                    modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 3.dp)
                ) {
                    items() {
                        MySinglePostItem()
                    }

                    posts.apply {
                        when {
                            //Other loadState here

                            // Show below view if no item is present in paging data 
                            loadState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && posts.itemCount < 1 -> {
                                NoContentView(Modifier.fillMaxSize())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NoContentView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_outlined_image_no_content)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.empty_posts_message),
                fontSize = 15.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Accompanist states in its [documentation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/#usage) `SwipeRefresh` needs some content that is scrollable in order to be able to react to swipe gestures.

So perhaps having too few elements Compose automatically makes a `LazyColumn`/`LazyVerticalGrid` non-scrollable in order to optimize things?

My best guess would be to show a Scrollable-Column when you have no items to show and a `LazyVerticalGrid` otherwise.

```kotlin
SwipeRefresh(...) {
    if (loadState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading && loadState.append.endOfPaginationReached && posts.itemCount < 1) {
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
            NoContentView(Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
    } else {
        LazyVerticalGrid(...) {
             // ...
        }
    }
}
```